# Delete selected items from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Is it possible to delete the value of a li by class from mysql?
I have tried using a form and a textarea, but I don't want to type in the text of what I want to delete.

**HTML:**

```
<form action='slettMelding.php' method="POST">
    <button class='fjern'>Fjern</button>
    <textarea name='slettTekst'></textarea>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
 $li = $_POST['slettTekst'];
 $sql = "DELETE FROM melding WHERE meldingTekst = '$li'";
 $result = $conn->query("$sql");
```

Comment: what do you mean by _"value of a li by class"_ ?

Comment: Please don't use PDO this way: you're injecting user input directly into your query instead of binding user input to placeholders in the query. PDO protects you from SQL injection but only when used correctly.

Comment: For example <li class='msg'>Hello</li>

Answer (score 0):

If you use the code described, it will delete the table row as the condition. What do you mean by "value of a li by class" would delete the list of lines like:

```
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
```

Would it be this?
If so you should use the foreach. If it is, I can just answer then.

-

Another way would be the following query:

```
DELETE FROM melding WHERE meldingTekst IN (1, 4, 6, 7)
```

Using a implode ();

Comment: My biggest problem is how to get the text from a <li> in to php.
Example: <li class='msg'>Hey</li>, If I click on the <li>Hey</li> then I want php to get that in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is prone to SQL injection. Please don't use this in production code. But yea, what you're posting could work.

Answer (score 0):

It may be your syntax in php, try this:

```
 $sql = "DELETE FROM melding WHERE meldingTekst = '".$li."'";
```

Look at the quotes and concatenate `$li` to your sql string.